# Find integer solutions for $m^3-n^2=2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find integer solutions for $m^3-n^2=2$

I have seen multiple solutions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683673/understanding-a-solution-to-m3-n2-2).

However, these have been complicated. I tried taking different modulos but could not achieve anything. My latest attempt included this:
$$m^3+1=n^2-1$$
$$(m+1)(m^2-m+1)=(n-1)(n+1)$$
But this does not help. Is there any solution that is easy. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For what it's worth, the equation
$$y^2 = x^3 - 2$$
defines an [elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve), with the two lattice points $(3, 5)$ and $(3, -5)$.

Comment: BTW, the equations
$$m^3 - n^2 = 2$$
and
$$m^3 + 1 = n^2 - 1$$
do not have the same solutions.

Comment: The method in the linked thread is from several textbooks on number theory. The reason is probably that it is the simplest solution known to mankind. Modular arithmetic is unlikely to do much good exactly because we have that solution $m=3,n=5$. With respect to any modulus there will be solutions congruent to that. Some kind of a descent might still be possible (compare to the standard proof of irrationality of  $\sqrt2$), but if one existed, surely the number theory books would use that instead.

Comment: You might ask to simply explain that solution instead.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris How that helps? Is there any method to find all lattice points on a given elliptic curve?

Comment: @taritgoswami:  I refer you to this [MathOverflow Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7907), and I quote: "Finding all the integral points on an elliptic curve is a non-trivial computational problem."

Comment: Any way, here are additional readings that may help in finding lattice/integer points on elliptic curves satisfying certain conditions:  [Nagell-Lutz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagell%E2%80%93Lutz_theorem) and [Mordell-Weil theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell%E2%80%93Weil_theorem).

Comment: How did you come to $m^3+1=n^2-1$ from $m^3-n^2=2$? (I.e. you have a typo in your calculations).